# How to extract coordinate values from intersections in one \begin{axis} environment to use in a second \begin{axis}.. environment in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to plot two graphs, side by side, in two separate `\begin{axis}...\end{axis}` environments using `pgfplots`. In one graph I want to plot the n curves y1=x^2, y2=2x^2,..., yn=nx^2. I then want to calculate the intersections of yi (i=1,..,n) and y=5, call this set {(xi,zi)}, and on the SECOND graph, produce a scatter plot of the data (zi,i).

I realise that the usual method is to post example `TeX`, but I really have no idea where to start with this and I think the problem is simple enough.

Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The minimal example is at least a document frame with `\documentclass{....}...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, such that users can start right off...

Comment: Can you at least set up a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) with first `axis`? That way those trying to help can focus on the solution as opposed to setting up the problem test case.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, fair enough. I've had a go and also slightly expanded the problem...

Here's an example code and corresponding image. The method for setting the colour for the two curves is something I pinched. The reason for doing it this way is that the data on the left is related to a combined surface and contour plot (not shown) with a colour scheme using the mapref colour scheme defined at the top.

The colours are chosen with values of -3.0 and -2.0.

The y-values of the data in the graph on the right shows the x-values of all the intersections (red and green circles) on the left. Green dots correspond to the top data on the right and red, lower. The x-values on the right are given by the colour values -3.0 and -2.0.

The problem is, given the colour values as one half of an  '\addplot[] coordinates{...};' input, how do I get pgfplots to automatically provide the y-values by interrogating the graph on the left.

[image]

```
  \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[]{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
    \pgfplotsset{
        colormap={mapref}{rgb255(0cm)=(0,0,128) rgb255(1cm)=(0,0,255) rgb255(3cm)=(0,255,255) rgb255(5cm)=(255,255,0) rgb255(7cm)=(255,0,0) rgb255(8cm)=(128,0,0)} % This is equivalent to a renamed jet colormap
    }
  \pagenumbering{gobble}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    , width=5cm
    , name=left
  ]
    \pgfplotscolormapaccess[-5:0]{-3.0}{mapref}
    \message{GOT \meaning\pgfmathresult^^J}%
    \def\TEMP{\definecolor{my color3.0}{rgb}}
    \expandafter\TEMP\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfplotscolormapaccess[-5:0]{-2.0}{mapref}
    \message{GOT \meaning\pgfmathresult^^J}%
    \def\TEMP{\definecolor{my color2.0}{rgb}}
    \expandafter\TEMP\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}

    \addplot[name path global=curve1, my color3.0]{x^2};
    \addplot[name path global=curve2, my color2.0]{2*x^2};
    \addplot[name path global=line]{9};
    \fill[red, name intersections={of=curve1 and line, name=int}](int-1) circle (0.1cm);
    \fill[green, name intersections={of=curve1 and line, name=int}](int-2) circle (0.1cm);
    \fill[red, name intersections={of=curve2 and line, name=int}](int-1) circle (0.1cm);
    \fill[green, name intersections={of=curve2 and line, name=int}](int-2) circle (0.1cm);
  %       \node[name intersections={of=curve and line, name=int}](int-1);
  \end{axis}
  \begin{axis}[
    , width=5cm
    , at={($(left.east)+(1.0cm,0)$)}
    , anchor=west
    , xmin=-5
    , xmax=0
    , ymin=-5
    , ymax=5
    , colormap name={mapref}
    , point meta min=-5 
    , point meta max=0
  ]
    \addplot[
      , scatter
      , scatter src=explicit
    ] coordinates{
      (-3.0,-3)[-3]
      (-2.0,-2.1213)[-2]
      };
    \addplot[
      , scatter
      , scatter src=explicit
    ] coordinates{
      (-3.0,3)[-3]
      (-2.0,2.1213)[-2]
      };
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```